# What is the use of yaml files in zephyr

Tags: device-tree, zephyr-rtos

I have started understanding zephyr

Looking into `samples/basic/blinky`, there is a file `sample.yaml`

From Documentation:

> Bindings are files in YAML format.
>   .dts files describe the available hardware devices, but don’t tell the
>   system which pieces of information are useful, or what kind of
>   configuration output (#define’s) should be generated. Bindings provide

Just to understand the importance, i moved the sample.yaml into our home folder and built, flashed the led blink application and it blinks.

Is it necessary to have yaml file in our application directory and when it is needed?

> this information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yaml files in zephyr are used for:

- binding information related to devicetree hardware description
- configuration of test cases

As you have already found, devicetree binding are documented [here](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/guides/dts/index.html#devicetree-bindings).

About zephyr test framework read all the details in the official [docs](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/guides/test/ztest.html)

In particular, `sample.yaml` files located inside the application project directory define tests cases
to be executed by the `sanitycheck` tool. Read [here](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/guides/test/sanitycheck.html#test-cases) for more details.

Comment: im working on fuel-gauge, my question is, what do you think about where the battery capacity should be placed in? it is as a config in Kconfig or  in dts binding yaml file

Comment: Personally I will prefer a Kconfig property for the capacity of the battery. I will keep things simple, unless you have already a dts model for the battery for other reasons. See here for more: https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/build/dts/dt-vs-kconfig.html